# How to use this code to create DataGridView columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I found this code on the web several months ago.  It is great for creating datagridview columns.  I have never used it to create a comboboxcolumn.  Now I need to do that and can't figure out how to assign values to the column.  And, I can't find where I first found this code.  I can find snippets of it now but nothing complete.

It's easy to create a textboxcolumn and create dgv rows with values in them.  But, I don't know how to create a comboboxcolumn.  By the way, in this case, the column can use the same combobox values for each row.

Here's the code I have:

I create a datatable to hold the data to be bound to the dgv:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable("Grid")
Dim dr As DataRow
dtSetupColumns(dt)

Public Sub dtSetupColumns(ByRef dt As DataTable)
        dt.Columns.Add("name_l", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("name_f", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("state", GetType(String))
End Sub
```

Assign values to the datatable:

```
dr = dt.NewRow()
dr("name_l") = ' from query table
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
```

Create the DataGridView Columns:

```
dgvCreateColumns(dgv)

Public Sub dgvCreateColumns(ByRef inDataGridView As DataGridView)
  With inDataGridView.Columns
    .Add(dgvCreateColumn(ColumnStyle.TextBoxColumn, String.Empty, "Last Name", "name_l", 80, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft))
    .Add(dgvCreateColumn(ColumnStyle.TextBoxColumn, String.Empty, "First Name", "name_f", 80, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft))
    .Add(dgvCreateColumn(ColumnStyle.ComboBoxColumn, String.Empty, "State", "state", 80, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft))
  End With
End Sub


Public Shared Function dgvCreateColumn(ByVal ColumnType As ColumnStyle, ByVal format As String, ByVal headerText As String, ByVal dataPropertyName As String, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal alignment As DataGridViewContentAlignment, Optional ByVal bMakeVisible As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal inReadOnly As Boolean = False) As DataGridViewColumn
        Dim dgvC As DataGridViewColumn = Nothing

        Select Case ColumnType
            Case ColumnStyle.ButtonColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewButtonColumn
            Case ColumnStyle.CheckBoxColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
            Case ColumnStyle.ComboBoxColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
            Case ColumnStyle.ImageColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewImageColumn
            Case ColumnStyle.LinkColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewLinkColumn
            Case ColumnStyle.TextBoxColumn
                dgvC = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        End Select

        With dgvC
            .DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = alignment
            .DefaultCellStyle.Format = format
            If ColumnType = ColumnStyle.ButtonColumn Then
                '.colum()
            End If
            .HeaderText = headerText
            .Name = headerText
            .ReadOnly = inReadOnly
            If width = 0 Then
                .Visible = False
            Else
                .Width = width
                If bMakeVisible = False Then
                    .Visible = False
                Else
                    .Visible = True

                End If
            End If
        End With

        Return dgvC
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go thru each Cell in each Row

```
For i as Integer = 0 to dgv.Rows.Count -1 
   Dim gridComboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
   gridComboBox.DataSource = dt
   gridComboBox.ValueMember = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
   dgv.Item(2, i) = gridComboBox 'Change the Cell in Column:2 Row:i to ComboBox
Next
```